# First Name Generator not working

Tags: c#, random

I was attempting to make a random name generator and this is the code I came up with:

```
 private void GenerateName()
    {
        if (GeneratedName == "")
        {
            GenerateConsonant();
            consonantCurrent = consonant1;
            GenerateVowel();
            vowelCurrent = vowel1;
            GenerateConsonant();
            consonantCurrent = consonant2;
            GenerateConsonant();
            consonantCurrent = consonant3;
            GenerateVowel();
            vowelCurrent = vowel2;
        }

        GeneratedName = consonant1 + vowel1 + consonant2 + consonant3 + vowel2;
    }

    private void GenerateConsonant()
    {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        GlobalVariables.random = randomNumber.Next(2, 22);

        if (GlobalVariables.random == 1)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "b";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 2)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "c";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 3)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "d";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 4)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "f";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 5)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "g";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 6)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "h";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 7)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "j";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 8)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "k";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 9)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "l";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 10)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "m";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 11)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "n";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 12)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "p";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 13)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "q";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 14)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "r";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 15)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "s";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 16)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "t";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 17)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "v";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 18)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "w";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 19)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "x";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 20)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "y";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 21)
        {
            consonantCurrent = "z";
        }
    }

    private void GenerateVowel()
    {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        GlobalVariables.random = randomNumber.Next(2, 6);

        if (GlobalVariables.random == 1)
        {
            vowelCurrent = "a";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 2)
        {
            vowelCurrent = "e";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 3)
        {
            vowelCurrent = "i";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 4)
        {
            vowelCurrent = "o";
        }
        if (GlobalVariables.random == 5)
        {
            vowelCurrent = "u";
        }
    }
}
```

}

After running it, I found it gave me a null result...
If there is an obvious error, please tell me as I am retarded :l
Or if it would never work you could show me a way you would do it and then I would attempt to adapt it to my program.

Btw, I am making a Grand Strategy game that would use this to generate random names for characters

Edit:
What I attempted to do was every time GenerateConsonant() and GenerateVowel() were called they would set a random character to the Current value. Then after each was set it would set itself to a certain consonant or vowel. After this they'd all be put together to form a first name...

Comment: For starters, your variable assignments in your first if statement are backwards.

Comment: `consonantCurrent = consonant1;` is backwards. You're assigning consonant1 to consonantCurrent. You need to have it the other way around in order to have GeneratedName actually have a value.

Comment: One problem is that you're creating a new `Random` instance every time you call `GenerateConsonant`. You should create the `Random` instance once at class scope (i.e. `private readonly Random RandomNumber = new Random();` Otherwise you'll get lots of duplicated consonants.

Comment: Any particular reason why are not returning consonant and vowels from the `GenerateConsonant()` and `GenerateVowel()` methods?

Comment: I just encountered names like lilli and memme so thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's fixed! I had to switch the variable assignments and get rid of the extra Random duplicates. What do you mean Adrian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logarr means that instead of having

```
consonantCurrent = consonant1;
```

You should have

```
consonant1 = consonantCurrent;
```

And the same goes for your other variable assignments.

In addition, I would recommend returning a consonant or vowel in your random functions rather than assigning it to `consonantCurrent` or `vowelCurrent`. It saves you a variable and is less confusing.

I'm not sure if these are part of a larger class, but make sure you are initializing your `consonant1` etc variables before assigning values to them.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of bugs in such a small amount of code:

- New instance of `Random` for each random number
- Incorrect range for random number generation
- Reversed assignment
- Not using `y` as a vowel?

Never mind the use of side-effects (class fields) instead of just returning values from methods, and the use of a huge series of `if` statements (not even `if`/`else if`!) to map an integer to a character.

Seems to me that something like this would be a lot easier to write correctly, and will be easier to read later:

```
    static readonly string[] _vowels = { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" };
    static readonly string[] _consonants =
        Enumerable.Range((int)'b', (int)'z' - (int)'b' + 1)
                  .Select(c => ((char)c).ToString())
                  .Except(_vowels)
                  .ToArray();

    static readonly Random _random = new Random();

    private static string GenerateName()
    {
        return GenerateConsonant()
            + GenerateVowel()
            + GenerateConsonant()
            + GenerateConsonant()
            + GenerateVowel();
    }

    private static string GenerateVowel()
    {
        return _vowels[_random.Next(_vowels.Length)];
    }

    private static string GenerateConsonant()
    {
        return _consonants[_random.Next(_consonants.Length)];
    }
```

I'll leave it up to you to decide whether to count 'y' as a vowel as well as a consonant, and if so how to implement that. :)

Answer (score 0):

all your code can fit into a simple method to generate a random name

at the class level assign the Random Class

```
Random rnd = new Random();

private string Generate_Name(int length)
    {

        string name = "";

        string[] letters = new string[21] { "b", "c", "d",
                                                "f", "g", "h", "j",
                                                "k", "l", "m", "n",
                                                "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
                                                "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};

        string[] vowels = new string[5] { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" };

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 2 || i == 4)
            {
                int index = rnd.Next(0, vowels.Length);
                name += vowels[index];
            }
            else
            {
                int index = rnd.Next(0, letters.Length);
                name += letters[index];
            }
        }

        return name;

    }
```

then you can change the code around to fit what you need!