# C# Code generator with vowels and consonants, vowels not showing up

Tags: c#, vb.net, random

I have a random key generator in C# that's supposed to generate a key in the following format:

consonant + vowel + consonant + vowel + four numerical digits

So for example it would be BABA1234 or ZUZU9876.

Currently, however, the vowels don't show up, though everything else does, so I end up getting output like B_B_1234, for example, where the underscores represent either spaces or unrecognized character boxes.

I've been looking through some examples such as [this](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/103440/), [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/af85cb68-20c0-4b25-9e43-9aa23a6135fd/generate-random-alphabet-only-vowels?forum=csharpgeneral) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286285/first-name-generator-not-working), but I still haven't gotten it to work. The C# code is as follows:

```
public static string shortText()
{
   string randomNumber = new Random().Next(1000, 9999).ToString();
   char c1 = consonant();
   char c2 = vowel();
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
   char c3 = consonant();
   char c4 = vowel();

   return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", c1, c2, c3, c4, randomNumber);
}

private static char vowel()
{
   int selected = new Random().Next(0, 4);
   List<int> list = new List<int> { 65, 69, 73, 79, 85 };

   return Strings.Chr(selected);
}

private static char consonant()
{
   int selected = new Random().Next(65, 90);
   List<int> list = new List<int> { 65, 69, 73, 79, 85 };

   if (list.Contains(selected) == false)
   {
       return Strings.Chr(selected);
   }
   else {
       return Strings.Chr(selected + 1);
   }
}
```

An additional note is that this code was originally written in VB (which is why there is a Strings.Chr in the C# code above, I added a reference to the VB library), where it worked correctly and generated codes according to the format in the beginning. I converted it over to C# and edited it slightly to remove the errors, but it looks like the conversion hasn't been perfect. Here is the VB code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnGenerateKey_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerateKey.Click
        txtKey.Text = shortText()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function shortText() As String
        Dim randomNumber As String = New Random().Next(1000, 9999).ToString
        Dim c1 As Char = consonant()
        Dim c2 As Char = vowel()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400)
        Dim c3 As Char = consonant()
        Dim c4 As Char = vowel()

        Return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", c1, c2, c3, c4, randomNumber)
    End Function

    Private Shared Function vowel() As Char
        Dim list As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)({65, 69, 73, 79, 85})

        Return Chr(list(New Random().Next(0, 4)))
    End Function

    Private Shared Function consonant() As Char
        Dim selected As Integer = New Random().Next(65, 90)
        Dim list As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)({65, 69, 73, 79, 85})

        If list.Contains(selected) = False Then
            Return Chr(selected)
        Else
            Return Chr(selected + 1)
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vowel()` is returning the value of the random number (i.e. 1-4), not an element from your vowel list.

Fix it by changing

```
return Strings.Chr(selected);
```

to

```
return Strings.Chr(list[selected]);
```

**Additional problems**

There are a couple of other problems with your code though.

1) You are not using Random correctly. Don't create a new Random instance each time you need a random number - create one instance and use it for all requests for a random number.

2) You are more likely to get the consonants 'b', 'f', 'j', 'p', 'v', due to your algorithm. Instead of taking the next letter if you get a vowel inside `consonant()`, you should just have a list of 21 chars, and grab a random entry from that list.

3) Why are you creating a list of `ints` to store your consonants? Why not create a list of chars and avoid casting. Doing it this way would have made your actual bug immediately obvious, as you would have got a compile error :)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you encode (`65`) and decode (`Strings.Chr`) characters? Why not *direct*:

```
private static Char[] s_Vowels = new Char[] {
  'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U',
};

private static Char[] s_Consonants = new Char[] {
  'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 
  'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
};

// Simplest, not thread safe
private static s_Random = new Random();

private static String shortText() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8);

  sb.Append(s_Consonants[s_Random.Next(s_Consonants.Length)]);
  sb.Append(s_Vowels[s_Random.Next(s_Vowels.Length)]); 
  sb.Append(s_Consonants[s_Random.Next(s_Consonants.Length)]);
  sb.Append(s_Vowels[s_Random.Next(s_Vowels.Length)]); 

  sb.Append(s_Random.Next(1000, 10000));

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Just a small thing:  `s_Random.Next(1000, 9999)` will never return the value 9999.  It will only ever go up to 9998.  The second parameter of `Next` is the _exclusive_ upper bound.

Comment: @Chris Dunawa: thank you! You're quite right: I should have *not*  copied and pasted the fragment from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not fetching an alphabetic value in your random function and list of vowels.
The Alphabet starts as ASCII `65` and forward.
Your code should look something like this:

```
private static string vowel()
{
   var random = new Random();
   var list = new List<int> { 65, 69, 73, 79, 85 };
   return Strings.Chr(list[random.Next(0, 4)]);
}
```

Same problem with `consonant`.
For good "randomness" you should not instantiate a new Random object every time, rather instead have it as a member field in the class and use it in all methods.
[Link to Ascii values](http://www.asciitable.com/)